# shlex include empty strings

Tags: python, shlex

```
sample = ",,"
values = shlex.shlex(sample, posix=True)
values.quotes = '"'
values.whitespace = ','
values.whitespace_split = True

received_output = list(values)
```

In the above code sample I would like to have `["", "", ""]` as the value of `received_output`, but `received_output` is simply an empty list `[]`. There does not seem to be any information regarding how to receive this expected behavior.

This works fine with `sample.split(',')`, but I would prefer using shlex since I have complex sentences with tokens which should not be split up if part of a group (such as latitude, longitude in the following example).

Another example:

```
sample = '9267,BELMONT,KEELER,,62.4,35.2,10/01/2012,Weekday,"(41.93897000, -87.73212000)"'

expected_output = ['9267', 'BELMONT', 'KEELER', '', '62.4', '35.2', '10/01/2012', 'Weekday', '(41.93897000, -87.73212000)']
retrieved_output = ['9267', 'BELMONT', 'KEELER', '62.4', '35.2', '10/01/2012', 'Weekday', '(41.93897000, -87.73212000)']
```

Comment: How about using csv.reader? `print(list(csv.reader([sample]))[0])`

Comment: "I have complex sentences with nested commas" - nested commas? How do you nest *commas*? And why did you come to the conclusion that `shlex` would be an appropriate tool for the job? `shlex` is designed for syntaxes resembling that of a Unix shell.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules) state: "It’s not possible to parse empty strings, even if quoted." Therefore, your pseudo example (of empty content) will never work. Perhaps if you provided an example of real content, we could be of more assistance.

Comment: @user2357112 I assume he means that commas are nested inside of quotes. Of course, with some real-world examples, this would be more clear.

Comment: @Waylan good point! I have updated the question with another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shlex docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#parsing-rules) state:

> - It’s not possible to parse empty strings, even if quoted.

If you want to include empty strings in your output, the shlex library is the wrong tool for the job.

As @PadraicCunningham points out in a comment, the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (Comma  Separated Values) library should work fine for this:

```
>>> list(csv.reader(['9267,BELMONT,KEELER,,62.4,35.2,10/01/2012,Weekday,"(41.93897000, -87.73212000)"']))[0]
['9267', 'BELMONT', 'KEELER', '', '62.4', '35.2', '10/01/2012', 'Weekday', '(41.93897000, -87.73212000)']
>>> list(csv.reader([',,']))[0]
['', '', '']
```

Comment: Yup, I decided to use csv reader and it works perfectly! Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

So I initially upvoted the other answer, but it turns out it's wrong. The quote from the documentation is from the section on non-Posix behavior, but by default Posix behavior is used. With Posix behavior you can get an empty string like this:

```
shlex.split('x ""')
# ['x', '']
```

Note that quotes don't separate words in Posix mode, so this happens:

```
shlex.split('x""')
# ['x']
```

This is a little confusing, but you can still get empty strings with shlex.

In your particular case, since you seem to be parsing CSV-like input anyway, using the CSV module makes sense.